# Python Thread class variable is blank

Tags: python, multithreading, class, class-variables

I've been trying to fix this issue for the past few hours, and i just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong!

I have a single python file:

```
REFRESH_RATE=10.0
MAX_SECONDS=30

class user_manager:
  users={}
  def __init__(self,queue,sign_properties):

    self.properties=sign_properties
    self.queue=queue
    self.lock=threading.Lock()
    t=threading.Thread(target=user_timer,args=(self.lock,))
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

  def add_user(self,macaddr,user_properties):
    self.lock.acquire()
    user_manager.users[macaddr]=user(user_properties)
    self.lock.release()

  def user_exists(self, macaddr):
    if macaddr in user_manager.users:
      return True
    return False

  def update_rssi_for_user(self, macaddr,rssi):
    self.lock.acquire()
    user_manager.users[macaddr].update_rssi(rssi)
    self.lock.release()

  def get_users(self):
    return user_manager.users



def user_timer(lock):
  while True:
    print 'Test'
    lock.acquire()
    print user_manager.users
    lock.release()
    format = '%H:%M:%S'
    for user in user_manager.users:
      first_seen=user_manager.users[user].get_first_seen()
      current_time=str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
      difference=datetime.strptime(current_time, format) - datetime.strptime(first_seen[1], format)
      print 'difference'+str(difference.seconds)
      if difference.seconds >30:
        user.expire()
        del user_manager.users[user]
    time.sleep(REFRESH_RATE)
```

The idea is that the user_manager class has a class variable called users, that is populated during runtime - this works perfectly.

Then I have a threaded function called user_timer that is started from the user_manager, which manages these users and expires them after X amount of time. This is removed from the context of this post as it's not relevant.

Currently, every time user_timer is called the result of `user_manager.users` is an empty dictionary `{}` but from outside of this file other modules can see the class variable as being populated.

What exactly am i doing wrong, and why does it work in this fashion?

James.

EDIT:

Calling class' constructor:

```
    class api_wrapper(object):
  def __init__(self,queue,display_queue,macaddr):
    self.properties={}
    self.queue=queue
    self.register_sign(macaddr)
    self.user_manager=user_manager(self.queue,self.properties)
    self.nearby_devices={}
    self.display_queue=display_queue
```

Calling function from the above class:

```
def handle_address(self,address,postcode):
if self.user_manager is None:
  return
if self.user_manager.user_exists(address):
  #print user_manager.users
  self.user_manager.update_address_for_user(address,postcode)
  #self.display_queue.put(self.user_manager.get_users())
elif macaddr not in self.nearby_devices:
  if self.check_address(address) is False:
    self.nearby_devices[address]=postcode
```

Comment: Any question including the phrase "This is removed from the context of this post as it's not relevant." usually means the relevant code has been removed. My guess would be you are using the `multiprocessing` module and each call to `user_timer` happens in a new process.

Comment: Okay, I'll add the code to the post - but I'm making 0 calls to the multiprocessing module... @Duncan Edit complete.

Comment: @James You have to provide us with enough code to reproduce the problem. Right now it doesn't look like you have.

Comment: @dano What would you like to see? The structure of the program is a bit complex,and a lot more code would need to be posted. However I can describe the architecture if that helps? I have three Processes that communicate using queues. The code provided is in a process where network communication is managed, the user_manager module is created in this process, and the thread is also created in this process. Would that work alright?

Comment: @James, Ideally, you would give us the minimum amount of code required for us to reproduce the issue on our own machines.

Comment: @dano unfortunately there are too many lines of code, and also a legal requirement for me not to publicise my code, I can however share the calling function and __init__ of the calling class if that would suffice? God this is so annoying. Sorry to be a pain. SEE EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by spawning it as a Process instead and using the shared state variable of manager.Dict()!

The thread i believe was copy the variables at the time of spawn, and because it was running in an almost 'separate' environment, the class variables weren't changing!

Thanks all.

James.

Answer (score 0):

When I add enough around your code to get it to run, it works for me at least as far as getting an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'` where you have mixed the `datetime` module with the `datetime` class within that module.

Not a lot of help I know, but I suspect the problem must lie outside the code you posted. `user_timer` sees the update to `user_manager.users` just fine:

```
import threading
import datetime

REFRESH_RATE=10.0
MAX_SECONDS=30

class user:
    def __init__(self, properties):
        self.properties = properties

    def get_first_seen(self):
        return 42

class user_manager:
  users={}
  def __init__(self,queue,sign_properties):

    self.properties=sign_properties
    self.queue=queue
    self.lock=threading.Lock()
    t=threading.Thread(target=user_timer,args=(self.lock,))
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

  def add_user(self,macaddr,user_properties):
    self.lock.acquire()
    user_manager.users[macaddr]=user(user_properties)
    self.lock.release()

  def user_exists(self, macaddr):
    if macaddr in user_manager.users:
      return True
    return False

  def update_rssi_for_user(self, macaddr,rssi):
    self.lock.acquire()
    user_manager.users[macaddr].update_rssi(rssi)
    self.lock.release()

  def get_users(self):
    return user_manager.users



def user_timer(lock):
  while True:
    print 'Test'
    lock.acquire()
    print user_manager.users
    lock.release()
    format = '%H:%M:%S'
    for user in user_manager.users:
      first_seen=user_manager.users[user].get_first_seen()
      current_time=str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
      difference=datetime.strptime(current_time, format) - datetime.strptime(first_seen[1], format)
      print 'difference'+str(difference.seconds)
      if difference.seconds >30:
        user.expire()
        del user_manager.users[user]
    time.sleep(REFRESH_RATE)


u = user_manager(None, None)
u.add_user("1234", "Properties")
raw_input()
```

Give me this output:

```
C:\temp>c:\python27\python t.py
Test
{'1234': <__main__.user instance at 0x02583A80>}
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "t.py", line 55, in user_timer
    difference=datetime.strptime(current_time, format) - datetime.strptime(first_seen[1], format)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 65, in <module>
    raw_input()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure there are errors in that section of code! I haven't had the opportunity to test it due to this threading error. After conducting more tests however, I can see what you are seeing. It's almost like the `user_manager.users` that user_timer is seeing, is entirely different to what the other modules are reading. Any thoughts?